# Plotly Dash / Python -- Interaction(s) between Dropdown, Graph and Rangeslider

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I've been getting into Python as a means to visualize data. I'm still very much of a novice. To practice I'm working with the gapminder dataset in Plotly Express in Jupyter Notebook. Been stuck on something I can't quite wrap my head around.

I have this container for a graph:

```
dcc.Graph(id='the_graph')
```

I've managed to create a dcc.RangeSlider that interacts with my linegraph. It looks something like this:

```
dcc.RangeSlider(
    id='the_year',
    min=data['year'].min(),
    max=data['year'].max(),
    value=[data['year'].min(), data['year'].max()],
    step=None,
    marks={str(x):str(x) for x in data['year'].unique()}
    )
```

So what I did here was provide the Slider with everything it needs. Next I created the dcc.Dropdown which looks something like this:

```
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='the_country',
        placeholder='Select country/countries',
        options=[
            {'label': x, 'value': x} for x in data['country'].sort_values().unique()
        ],
        multi=True
   )
```

Here I wanted to fill the dropdown with all the countries in my data in alphabetical order. That also worked after figuring out how to use a loop to make my life a bit easier.

So far so good. But here is where it goes wrong. I'm able to adjust the graph based on the Slider, but the Dropdown does nothing and I fail to understand why.

```
@app.callback(
    Output('the_graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('the_year', 'value'),
    Input('the_country', 'value')]
)

def update_graph(sel_year, sel_country):
    dff = data[(data['year']>=sel_year[0]) & (data['year']<=sel_year[1])]
    
    graph = px.line(
        dff,
        x=dff['year'],
        y=dff['pop'],
        color=dff['country'],
        markers=True,
    )
    
    return graph
```

In the callback, I found out multiple inputs are an option when put into a list. So I gave it a go: The output should be put into 'the_graph', which it does. The dff line is to filter based on year selected in the Slider. If I understood correctly, a function can have more than one argument and is processed left to right.

What I expected to happen was that since I'm taking the value of my Slider and the value of my Dropdown, it would 'filter' the graph based on those selections. However, only the Slider seems to work.

Is my approach wrong? Am I missing something obvious here? I feel it should be possible to have multiple things (slider AND dropdown) decide what is shown in a graph.

Any help / guidance would be very much appreciated.

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add conditions for `Dropdown`. Something as below:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('the_graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('the_year', 'value'),
    Input('the_country', 'value')]
)

def update_graph(sel_year, sel_country):
    dff = data[(data['year']>=sel_year[0]) & (data['year']<=sel_year[1])]
    if sel_country == []:
        dff_2 = dff.copy()
    elif sel_country != []:
        dff_2 = dff[dff['country'].isin(sel_country)]
    
    graph = px.line(
        dff_2,
        x=dff_2['year'],
        y=ddff_2['pop'],
        color=dff_2['country'],
        markers=True,
    )
    
    return graph
```

Comment: I see. I created the Dropdown but hadn't yet done anything with it. I don't know how I failed to see that, but alas.

Thank you for your input! I'll be trying to make this work. Thanks again and have a great day.